# Completely overwrite 2 branches with another?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I've seen a couple SO threads regarding overwriting branches with another, but the answers seemed like they would cause problems in my situation so decided to ask.

I have a branch, `redesign`, which is the current updated code that I want to use. I also have a `master` and `development` branch, which are very outdated. Both the `master` and `development` branch are also on Github, and have been cloned by another member on my team.

What I want to do, is overwrite the `master` & `development` branch to contain only the current code in the `redesign` branch. Basically, all three branches should contain identical code at the end. I would also want to update the `master` and `development` branches on Github to reflect their updated state when everything is done, so my teammate can download the updated versions.

When searching for a solution to this, the most common answer I seemed to find was using git merge with the --ours flag:

`git merge -s ours`

This sounds like it would merge the branches and overwrite conflicts with the proper code from the `redesign` branch, but wouldnt this also leave any non-conflicting code in the branch?

Whats the best way to go about achieving all this?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the information you provided, it seems like you don't care about the content in the master and development branches, and you are trying to overwrite those branches with whatever is on your redesign branch.

I think the easiest and most straightforward way to accomplish this is:

1. Delete the branches you don't care about (master and development)

   `git branch -D master`

   `git branch -D development`
2. Create those branches off of the redesign branch.

   `git checkout redesign`

   `git checkout -b 'master'`

   `git checkout -b 'development'`
3. Force push those branches to your remote.

   `git push origin master -f`

   `git push origin development -f`

Comment: Wont this cause a ton of issues for my teammate who already has cloned the repo with the old branches? While I dont care about the old code in the master and development branches, ideally id like to still preserve the history. Deleting the branches seems like bad practice...but noted.

Comment: Assuming that you and your teammate do not care about the old branches, you can do what I mentioned above and then have your teammate reset his branches to the new ones by doing: `git checkout master` and `git reset --hard origin/master` (same for development branch). If you would like to preserve the history of the old branch just for the sake of it, you can create a new branch off of master before resetting it like so: `'git checkout -b 'master_old'`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info. Another thing, the `git merge -s ours` strategy, would it in fact completely overwrite all code in the old branches? Or would non-conflicting code in the old branches stay?

Comment: No, it will not overwrite all code in the old branches.